# Taking HTML input field results and printing them onto a PDF contract

Tags: php, html, wordpress, pdf

I'm trying to take the results from an input form on an HTML page and have them pasted or printed onto a PDF contract upon submission.

I'm using wordpress cforms, but I'm not opposed to exploring non-wordpress solutions for this because I don't think there are any simple widgets to do this.

I've come across some mentions of using the Zend Framework to achieve this, but I was hoping for a different solution.

Comment: Ever heard of http://www.tcpdf.org?

Comment: Is your contract in PDF format already? If so, I'd try a PHP PDF library that allows you to load a PDF and write on it. Not sure which one that is - FPDF maybe?

Comment: @halfer yes the contract is in PDF form already, with a few blanks for a customer to fill in appropriate fields (i.e. name, initials, address, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using tools such as [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) you can achieve this through a third party method to output your current html output to a PDF format.

Here is a small PHP code snippet on how tcpdf works

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf.class.php');
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($HTMLoutput);
    $html2pdf->Output('Report.pdf');
    die;
```

there are some other frameworks on moving your other type of outputs from a plugin but I do not think it has exactly what you want since it is based on posts and pages

http://wordpress.org/plugins/post2pdf-converter/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-to-pdf/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Robert. I'll look over the documentation in tcpdf link. One question though, because I'm not sure I made it clear in my original post, but I'm looking to take the values from input fields, then paste them in the appropriate blanks on my pre-made PDF contract. (i.e. HTML page has the following fields: name, address, phone number. Then I will print the input results throughout the contract in every applicable blank space). I'm not trying to turn my HTML page into a PDF. Is that within tcpdf's capabilities?

Comment: yes as long as you put the values into the $HTMLoutput you can achieve this.  since you already have a HTML output with all the values, as long as you put that into the $HTMLoutput variable it will work.